# How do I find the how much is the value of a key in python, when the dictionary is in another file?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am making this coffee machine and my dictionary is in another file. How do I find how much more resource is needed to make a particular type of coffee?

```py
if main.resources.keys('ingredients') >= main.resources:
    print("Sorry enough ingredients are'nt available." + main.resources + "is only left but " + choice + "requires" + 
           "")
```

this is the code

this is the dictionary in another file

```py
"espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 100,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 150,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 200,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}
```

I expected it to give me how much more of the particular item is needed. So if the coffee isn't enough it should tell me that you need 10 coffee more by specifying what I need more.

Comment: (1) Are you sure you need Python 2.7? It's been out-of-support for years. (2) Please include an example of the output showing the issue. Are you getting any error? Or is the answer simply wrong? (3) Your dictionary file seems to be missing something at the beginning, the syntax is not valid.

Comment: `if main.resources.keys('ingredients') >= main.resources` does not make any sense.  It seems to assume that `main.resources` is a `dict`, but in that case, it is not a suitable operand for `>=`.  Also, the one object presented that is named `resources` does not have `'ingredients'` among its keys.

Comment: Too much is missing to write a definitive answer to the question, but it looks like you may want to look up the ingredient dict for the item of interest, and then check for having enough of *each* ingredient.  That would involve iterating over the entries in the ingredients dict to check them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```py
required = {
    "water": 500,
    "coffee": 80,
}
available = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

missing = []
for ingredient, required_amount in required.items():
    available_amount = available.get(ingredient, 0)
    if required_amount > available_amount:
        missing.append((ingredient, required_amount-available_amount))

for ingredient, missing_amount in missing:
    print(f'You need {missing_amount} more {ingredient}.')
# You need 200 more water.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! This was my first stackoverflow question and I am just a begginer. Thanks again!